# Invariant volume element on the Poincaré plane

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm trying to show $d\mu=\frac{dx\space dy}{y^2}$ is an invariant volume element under the action of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Since I know $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is generated by $
\begin{bmatrix}
a&\\
&a^{-1}
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1&b\\
&1
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
&-1\\
1&
\end{bmatrix}
$, I only need to show that the given volume element is invariant under these actions. I checked for the first two but the last one is giving me some trouble.

For $S=
\begin{bmatrix}
&-1\\
1&
\end{bmatrix}$,
$Sz=-\frac{1}{z}=-\frac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}=-\frac{x-iy}{|z|^2}.$
 So we have $x\to-\frac{x}{|z|^2}$ and $y\to\frac{y}{|z|^2}.$ So $S$ takes $|y|^{-2}dx\,dy\to |z|^4|y|^{-2}d\left(\frac{-x}{|z|^2}\right)d\left(\frac{y}{|z|^2}\right)=-|y|^{-2}dx\,dy.$ Why am I off by $-1$?

Comment: Examining change-of-measure (talking about positive, regular, Borel measures, etc) by change-of-variables effects on differential _forms_ can easily introduce signs, but/and the _measure_ transforms by the absolute values. This kind of non-issue already occurs on the real line...

Comment: @paulgarrett: Yeah, but that's not what's going on, in fact. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin, ah, I see that you're right... But/and I try to make myself immune to variations on this "(non-) problem" by the declaration that "it cannot possibly be an issue". Certainly good to be able to avoid misleading computational errors, though, in any case! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather do the calculation in complex coordinates altogether. If $w=f(z)=-1/z$, then 
$$f^*\frac{\frac i2 dw\wedge d\bar w}{\text{Im}(w)^2} = \frac{\frac i2 \frac{dz}{z^2}\wedge \frac{d\bar z}{\bar z^2}}{\frac{\text{Im}(z)^2}{|z|^4}} = \frac{\frac i2 dz\wedge d\bar z}{\text{Im}(z)^2},$$
as desired.

Your computation is quite suspect, in that you never computed $d(\frac x{|z|^2}) = d(\frac x{x^2+y^2})$. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
d\big({-}\frac x{x^2+y^2}\big)\wedge d\big(\frac y{x^2+y^2}\big) &= \frac{((x^2-y^2)dx+2xy\,dy)\wedge(-2xy\,dx+(x^2-y^2)dy)}{(x^2+y^2)^4}\\&=\frac{\big((x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2\big)dx\wedge dy}{|z|^8} = \frac{dx\wedge dy}{|z|^4},
\end{align*}
and it works out perfectly. In particular, let me emphasize that you need to be computing with differential forms here. As a tangential comment, let me say that $SL(2,\Bbb R)$ acts by orientation-preserving transformations, and so you cannot end up changing the sign of the area $2$-form.